# What maven plugin to use in pom.xml for automation tests testNG, java, rest-assured framework?

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, maven-plugin, rest-assured

I have created maven based testNG, rest-assured framework using Java. Now I want to integrate with Jenkins. What maven plugin to use in order to run via Jenkins?

Comment: I don't think you need any plugin for that. Do you already have a Jenkins server running? If answer is no, firstly I recommend you to follow this tutorial: https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven. Once you have your application building in Jenkins, your tests should be executed as part of Maven test goal: `mvn test`.

Comment: @carlosvin Yes, we have Jenkins server but CI job is not created yet. mvn test runs tests in my local but not in my colleague's.